# Number of bits for a scalar product

Tags: vectors, computer-science, binary, binary-operations, computer-algebra-systems

let's consider two vectors $v_1[i]$, $v_2[i]$, for $i = 0, 1, ... , N-1$.

Suppose you want to calculate the scalar product between them: it is simply the sum of all $v_1[i] * v_2[i]$ terms $(i=0,...,N-1)$.

Suppose now that each element of $v_1, v_2$ may be written as a $M$ - bits binary number. How many bits are the necessary to express the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each product, the maximum result is

$$
(2^M - 1)^2 = 2^{2M} - 2^{M+1} + 1
$$

Let $q = log_2N \Leftrightarrow N = 2^q$, then the biggest number you might get from your dot product is

$$
 N(2^{2M} - 2^{M+1} + 1) = 2^{2M+q} - 2^{M+q+1} + 2^q
$$

which means you might need $2M+\mathtt{ceil}(q)$ bits